React library debugging and conribution. Debug Reactjs. Source code
I followed Development Workflow steps to start my research in React library.
However, I got stuck on last step with build command
yarn build react/index,react-dom/index --type=UMD
When I run this line in my build folder I see only facebook-www folder and react-native folder

I found one similar issue on github. It didn't help me - yarn build nothing
Then I have tried to do with --type=NODE or CJS, ESM and only NODE worked.
Now I have oss-experimental/react-dom and react folders. However, they have cjs, not umd folders as expected in dev.html file


What can I do? My goal is to investigate and learn how React works.
I try to understand by source code, but it would be great to debug it by myself with code, not bundled code.
I want to see what happens under the hood, debug it and finally start to contribute.

I figured out how to do it. The problem was in React version.
Current 19.0.0 version doesn't support umd. https://react.dev/blog/2024/04/25/react-19-upgrade-guide#umd-builds-removed
I decided to use 18.2.0. This solved my issue.
